# Where and how do I read logs for a specific app?

Tags: logging

I know there are a lot of threads about android logs but I can't find an answer to this:

Where and how do I read logs for a specific app?

I have installed the Android SDK, connected my device and launched Eclipse and choose DDMS. Now, the Logcat is being generated but it does not seem to contain logging for specific apps. The colomn Application remains empty. I've tried different apps and different filters in logcat (debug,error etc) but I don't see application names appear.

Answer (score 2):

"Application Name" when it comes down to DDMS and `adb` means the *package name* of an Android application. Therefore when creating an DDMS logcat filter, you have to enter the applications package, for example for Google Maps `com.google.android.apps.maps`.

[image]